# Apigee - how to redirect to a different resource

Tags: proxy, apigee

I have an API proxy created with Apigee which works properly. However, I want to make a change in a resource name.

Currently, I have the following resource:

`<proxy>/collection/{Id}/product`s which redirects to `<myService>/collection/{Id}/products`

I want to rename the proxy resource like this:

`<proxy>/collection/{Id}/apps` which redirects to `<myService>/collection/{Id}/products`

What is the best way to to that with Apigee?

Cheers,
Chavdar

Comment: What's the existing xml you've got? And which endpoint (proxy or target) is this on?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "redirect". Would you like to send a `Location` header back, or are you trying to proxy to a different path on your target?

Comment: I am trying to proxy to a different target. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to proxy requests for `/collection/{id}/apps` to `/collection/{id}/products`, add a JavaScript policy to the target request with the following snippet of code:

```
var collection_id = 10; //you should get this using context.getVariable()
var path = '/collection/' + collection_id + '/products'; //new path
var current_target_url = context.getVariable('target.url'); //get the existing target url
context.setVariable('target.copy.pathsuffix', false); //tell apigee to not copy the path over to the target
context.setVariable('debug.js.path', current_target_url + path); //this line is only for seeing the value in the trace tool
context.setVariable('target.url', current_target_url + path); //set the new path
```

Comment: Tried this. Looks like a working approach. The only issue is that this will redirect all resources to products, not only apps. I've tried to do this in the proxy request:
var collection_id = 1; // you should get this using context.getVariable()
var path = '/collection/' + collection_id + '/products'; //new path
var current_request_path = context.getVariable('request.path'); //get the existing request path
context.setVariable('request.path', path); // set the new path

This didn't work.. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to set the new URL on target, since that's where the request will be going. You could wrap the code with a condition: `if(context.getVariable('proxy.pathsuffix') == "/collection/{id}/apps"){...}`. Alternatively, add the same logic to the `<Condition>` of the JavaScript `<Step>`